# Merging hashes of keyed arrays where all arrays have been zipped together

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, merge

I have one or many (it might be 1000) hashes from a DB call. In this case, I have two:

```
{ "water_need"=>[9959, 9959, 9959, 9959, 9959, 9959, 9959, 9959, 9959, 9959, 9959, 9959], "forecast_savings"=>[-2479, -2479, -2479, -2479, -2479, -2479, -2479, -2479, -2479, -2479, -2479, -2479], "water_actual"=>[7480, 7480, 7480, 7480, 7480, 7480, 7480, 7480, 7480, 7480, 7480, 7480] }
{ "water_need"=>[21090, 21090, 21090, 21090, 21090, 21090, 21090, 21090, 21090, 21090, 21090, 21090], "forecast_savings"=>[-20890, -20890, -20890, -20890, -20890, -20890, -20890, -20890, -20890, -20890, -20890, -20890], "water_actual"=>[200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200] }
```

Each hash has the same keys. Each hash has the same length array as the value for the keys. It is possible that some array have `nil`.  If all values are `nil`, the array is still a 12-length array of all `nil`s.

The goal is to return a single hash having the same keys as the hashes and the arrays added together as the value. Expected result:

```
{ "water_need"=>[31049, 31049, 31049, 31049, 31049, 31049, 31049, 31049, 31049, 31049, 31049, ], "forecast_savings"=>[-23369, -23369, -23369, -23369, -23369, -23369, -23369, -23369, -23369, -23369, -23369, -23369], "water_actual"=>[7680, 7680, 7680, 7680, 7680, 7680, 7680, 7680, 7680, 7680, 7680, 7680] }
```

I found this way to add arrays:

```
def add_arrays(first, *others)
  first.zip(*others).map { |column| column.reduce(&:+) }
end
```

My thought is to map the similar keys into some new variable that holds all the `'water_needs'` for example, then feed the set to the `add_arrays` method returning the added value. I came here to get some guidance about the right way to do this.

UPDATE:

I worked on this in the afternoon.  Here is my solution so far but it doesn't properly handle nils:

```
    @month = []
    @water_need = []
    @cost_need = []
    @forecast_savings = []
    @forecast_cost_savings = []
    # @etc_padding = []
    @water_actual = []
    @reduction_amount = []

    @benchmark.each_with_index do |record, index|
      @water_need[index]             = record['water_need']
      @cost_need[index]              = record['cost_need']
      @forecast_savings[index]       = record['forecast_savings']
      @forecast_cost_savings[index]  = record['forecast_cost_savings']
      # @etc_padding[index]            = record['etc_padding']
      @water_actual[index]           = record['water_actual']
      @reduction_amount[index]       = record['reduction_amount']
    end

    @water_need_total             = @water_need.transpose.map(&:sum)
    @cost_need_total              = @cost_need.transpose.map(&:sum)
    @forecast_savings_total       = @forecast_savings.transpose.map(&:sum)
    @forecast_cost_savings_total  = @forecast_cost_savings.transpose.map(&:sum)
    # @etc_padding_total            = @etc_padding.transpose.map(&:sum)
    @water_actual_total           = @water_actual.transpose.map(&:sum)
    @reduction_amount_total       = @reduction_amount.transpose.map(&:sum)

    @cumulative_baseline = { month: month_array,
                             water_need: @water_need_total,
                             cost_need: @cost_need_total,
                             forecast_savings: @forecast_savings_total,
                             forecast_cost_savings: @forecast_cost_savings_total,
                             # etc_padding: @etc_padding_total,
                             water_actual: @water_actual_total,
                             reduction_amount: @reduction_amount_total
                           }

    ap @cumulative_baseline
```

'ap' is awesome print (a gem for console formatting) in case anyone is wondering.

The code isn't finished, and my style of writing code tends to be writing things out the long way first so that everything is clear in my head and then re-factoring by finding abstractions and pulling them out.  This is the current state of the code - not to suggest it's final form.

@benchmark is the object that contains all the hashes.  It's an array of records (common for an ActiveRecord call), and the records are a hash where the key is as I've written (e.g. water_need) and the value of that key is the array in question.

Comment: Your example implies that all the values in a single array are the same. If that is the case, then there is smell in the data you have; they are redundant. If that is not the case, then your example is misleading and inappropriate.

Comment: 12 elements per array representing 12 months in the year.  Sometimes the numbers are the same, sometimes they aren't.  Them being the same or not has no bearing on the task of adding up multiple arrays of the same 'type'.

Answer (score 1):

```
hashes = [
  {a: [1,2], b: [1, 2], c: [100, 200]},
  {a: [3,nil], b: [nil, nil], c: [300, 400]},
  {a: [5,4], b: [1, 2], c: [nil, nil]},
]

result = hashes.reduce {|h, v|
  h.merge(v) do |k, o, n|
    o.zip(n).map {|a, b| a.to_i + b.to_i }
  end
}

require 'pp'
pp result
```

**Output**

```
{:a=>[9, 6], :b=>[2, 4], :c=>[400, 600]}
```

**Explanation**

`merge` [takes a block argument](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that specifies *how* to merge the two hashes. In this case, the way to merge them is by adding the arrays together, the same way you did with `add_arrays`. The initial `hashes.reduce` will be automatically seeded with the first element of the array.

Comment: This doesn't appear to scale as there could be many arrays c, d, e, f, and so on.

Comment: it works for any number of arrays, as demonstrated by including both `:a` and `:b`. I could also include `:c`, `:d` etc and it would still work. What input were you thinking of that breaks it?

Comment: I added a third array `:c` to my answer to demonstrate. FWIW I feel `merge` is the correct way of tackling this problem because it expresses the _intent_ of what you are trying to do: merge multiple things together.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following.

**Code**

```
def totals_by_key(arr)
  arr.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |g,h|
       g.each { |k,v| h[k] << v } }
     .tap { |h| h.each { |k,v|
       h[k] = v.transpose.map { |c| c.compact.reduce(0,:+) } } }
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = [{ "water_need"       =>[  9959,   9959,   9959],
         "forecast_savings" =>[ -2479,  -2479,  -2479],
         "water_actual"     =>[  7480,   7480,   7480] },
       { "water_need"       =>[ 21090,  21090,  21090],
         "forecast_savings" =>[-20890, -20890, -20890],
         "water_actual"     =>[   nil,    nil,    nil] }]

totals_by_key(arr)
  #=> {"water_need"         =>[ 31049,  31049,  31049],
  #    "forecast_savings"   =>[-23369, -23369, -23369],
  #    "water_actual"       =>[  7480,   7480,   7480]}
```

**Explanation**

```
f = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |g,h|
  g.each { |k,v| h[k] << v } }
  #=> { "water_need"       =>[[ 9959,  9959,  9959], [ 21090,  21090,  21090]],
   #     "forecast_savings" =>[[-2479, -2479, -2479], [-20890, -20890, -20890]],
   #     "water_actual"     =>[[ 7480,  7480,  7480], [   nil,    nil,    nil]] }
```

Within `tap`'s block. `each` passes each key-value pair of `h` into its block, the first being:

```
"water_need" => [[ 9959,  9959,  9959], [ 21090,  21090,  21090]]
```

so the block variables are assigned:

```
k = "water_need"
v = [[ 9959,  9959,  9959], [ 21090,  21090,  21090]]
```

The following operations are then performed:

```
t = v.transpose
  #=> [[9959, 21090], [9959, 21090], [9959, 21090]] 
u = t.map { |c| c.compact.reduce(0,:+) }
  #=> [31049, 31049, 31049]
```

The latter operation sums the values of each element (array) of `t`, after removing `nil`'s. `map` does this by passing each element of `t` into its block, the first being:

```
c = [9959, 21090]
```

so

```
d = c.compact
  #=> [9959, 21090] 
d.reduce(0,:+)  
  #=> 31049
```

The other two key-value pairs of `f` above are processed similarly. `tap` then returns `h`, which in turn is returned by the method.

Note that if:

```
a = [nil, nil, nil]
b = a.compact
[].reduce(0,:+) 
  #=> 0
```

whereas

```
[].reduce(:+) 
  #=> nil
```

**A variant**

Instead of:

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |g,h|
  g.each { |k,v| h[k] << v } }
```

you could write:

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| g.each { |k,v| (h[k] ||= []) << v } }
```

Comment: I'm going to try this out tomorrow - it's a bit too abstract for me upon first reading - you have a gift :)

Comment: Thanks, notaceo, but it's not a gift; it's just gaining experience with the language. When I was new to Ruby I felt like I was stumbling in the dark. As with any new language, initially you must translate every word. After awhile your subconscious will handle some of those chores, allowing you to think about how you can combine words. Then you start recognizing patterns. Think back to when you were learning calculus. After considerable practice you could look at a problem and your brain would instantly shout out "integration by parts!".